# Spreadsheets to calendar depending on the decision of an operator

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello I am making a script that takes data from a worksheet (which receives data from a form) creates an event in my main calendar depending on the decision of an operator.

It receives the data from the form in columns A through F. In column G the operator decides whether to "Yes" or "No".

If G is "Yes" the script checks in column H if something is written. If it is empty
The script writes to column H and creates an event with the data of A: F,
If not something is written in column H it simply passes to the next line until the last one is written.

My script works correctly only if the entire H column is empty. This forces me to always clear column H and duplicate events already written to the calendar with each new entry.

How do I get the script to continue running without having to clear the H column?

My script is:

```
function teste() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var dados = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
var ultimaLinha = ss.getLastRow() - 1;
var options = {
    description: dados[ultimaLinha][2],
    location: dados[ultimaLinha][5],
};
for (var i = 1; i < ultimaLinha + 1; i++) {
    var validacao = dados[i][6];
    var escrita = dados[i][7];
    if (validacao === "Yes") {
        if (escrita == null) {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue('ok');
            var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEvent(
                dados[i][1],
                new Date(dados[i][3]),
                new Date(dados[i][4]),
                options);
        }
    }
}
```

My worksheet

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `getValues()` the empty cells in the data array still exist, they just contain an empty string. Change `null` to `""`

```
if (escrita == "") {
 ...  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your summary correctly, I think you need to remove the following check.

```
 if (escrita == null) {
```

Comment: When I remove that line the script creates duplicate events for the events that have already been processed previously